# Trying to mock a class so it won't execute constructor in phpUnit

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, microservices, httprequest

I'm testing a controller which possess an object that throws exception in it's constructor each time I do a test because the constructor check some environment variables aren't empty (but they are empty during the test). I tried mocking the class with getMockBuilder()->disableOriginalConstructor(), createMock, Mockery::mock()->makePartial(), I tried doing it in the setUp() before and after calling parent::setUp, I tried doing everything in the unit test instead of setUp(), they all execute the constructor and I don't understand why!

Here is an example of test:

```
public function setUp(): void
{
   self::$mockClient = $this->createMock('App\Helpers\Client');
   parent::setUp();
}

public function testSuccessfullyPost()
{
   $input_data = [
      'name' => 'valid name',
      'email' => 'valid@email.com'
   ];

   $this->json('POST', $this->testUri, $input_data, ['authentication' => $this->getToken()]);
   $this->seeStatusCode(201);
}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

I am using phpUnit 9.5.10

Answer (score 1):

I’ve used the following in the past:

```
$this->mockSchema = $this->getMockBuilder('Drupal\sqlsrv\Driver\Database\sqlsrv\Schema')
      ->setMethods(['getDefaultSchema', '__construct'])
      ->setMockClassName('MockSchema')
      ->setConstructorArgs([NULL])
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
$this->mockSchema->method('getDefaultSchema')->willReturn('dbo');
```

If you disable the original constructor, I think you still need to “set the method” to prevent the parent constructor from executing.